# How to import a class using brython?

Tags: python, brython

In recent day I've doing a mini-project (Conway's Game of Life) with python.

I want to do the GUI for the browser, so I decided to use a library called brython, that allow me to use python in the client side (is an interpreter, transforming python code to js code).

The problem I am currently having is that I can't import classes from other file, with the import line.

The structure of folder and files is the next:
Game

- Web

  - Game

    - _ _ init _ _.py
    - Cell.py
    - Game.py
- index.css
- index.html
- index.py

index.py is the file that will be execute when the page is charged. The same has this lines that generate the error (when I commented the error disappear but I can't use what I have to use, lol):
`import Game.Game as Game`

Game.py has a similar line that generate the same error too:

`from Game.Cell import Cell`

The console in the browser shows the next line: **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (File not found)**

And this too: **Error 404 means that Python module Game was not found at url http://localhost:8000/Game/Web/Game.py**

So, the problem is I'm not specifying well the URL, but I don't know how to solve it. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also include the `Web` forlder to the import. Therefore, your import should be like this: `import Web.Game.Game as Game` and `from Web.Game.Cell import Cell`. Also, don't forget to add `<script type="text/javascript" src="brython_stdlib.js"></script>` in your `index.html` for these imports to work.

More in https://brython.info/static_doc/en/import.html.